# CreateDirectory fails with error 123 when used with a long path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, create-directory

I am trying to overcome the MAX_PATH limit on the paths for win32 APIs. As suggested in the msdn documentation for these APIs (i.e. CreateDirectory), I have tried with '\\?\' pre-pended to the path but keep on getting the error 123.

Here is my code -

```
wstring path = L"\\\\?\\D:\\<LongPath>";
if(!CreateDirectory(path.c_str(), NULL)) //translates to CreateDirectoryW 
{
 // Get the error using GetLastError()
}
```

Error 123 stands for - "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.". Is there something else that i need to do differently?

Comment: Just for fun, can you show us one of these paths? Also, what is the volume format (FAT, FAT32, NTFS, etc..) ? Finally, does any single sub-componant of this super-long-path exceed 255 characters (typical, use `GetVolumeInformation()` to know the exact limitation)?

Comment: The volume format is NTFS. One of the directories in the path had more than 255 characters which was causing the issue. After i fixed that, CreateFirectory works for path lengths greater than 255. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Folder name can not contains some special chars like ?:/*"<>

Comment: the path prefix \\?\ is used to allow for long paths.  It is allowed